Inner product of sorted Gaussian vector
Let $X_i, Y_i \stackrel{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim} N(0,1)$, sort the $X_i$ and $Y_i$ in increasing order, and then compute the inner product of those two vectors. If $X_{(i)}$ denotes the $i$-th order statistic this can be written as
$$T = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_{(i)} Y_{(i)}$$
It seems true by simulation that
$$T \stackrel{p}{\to} 1$$
I am unable to prove this, but had the following idea. If we let $\hat{Q}_X$ and $\hat{Q}_Y$ be the empirical quantile function of the sample then I can write this as an integral:
$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n\hat{Q}_X(i/n) \hat{Q}_Y(i/n) = \int_0^1 \hat{Q}_X(u) \hat{Q}_Y(u) du \stackrel{?}{\to} \int_0^1 (\Phi^{-1}(u))^2 du = 1$$
This limit seems like a quantile function analogue of Glivenko-Cantelli, but I am unsure if there is a result like this and was unable to find it online.
I've seen this post, but they don't prove why the integral converges.
Update 9/1/24: I've tried this for other distributions and it seems to work as long as the second moment is finite. The answer below gives a nice proof for the uniform distribution, but it is unclear if the approach can be generalized due to the fact that $E(X_{(i)}) \to \infty$ in the unbounded case. The fact that it works for distributions without an MGF like $t_3$ makes me think that there should be another approach to solve the problem.
One thought is that for the case of an arbitrary bounded random variable $X_i$, then the DCT can be applied to the above integral as long as $\hat{Q}_X(u) \to \Phi^{-1}(u)$ almost surely for every $u$. However, I am also unable to prove this.

Another approach would be enough to bound the variance of $X_{(i)}$.  If $X_{(i)}$ has small variance for most $i$, then $Y_{(i)}$ and $X_{(i)}$ should be close and so we'd have $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{(i)} Y_{(i)} \approx \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{(i)} X_{(i)}$ which is an estimator for $E[X^2] = 1$.

I think this is most of the way there, but maybe someone else can fill in the gaps:
Let $X_{i}\sim \square[0,1]$ and $Y_{i}\sim \square[0,1]$ i.i.d. where $\square$ is a distribution with continuous and strictly increasing CDF $F$, mean $0$, and variance $0$. Let $T=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_{(i)}Y_{(i)}$. We will show $T\xrightarrow{p}1$.
Since $F$ is continuous and strictly increasing, $F^{-1}=Q$ exists as the quantile function for $\square$. By the probability integral transform, we can write $(X_{(1)},...,X_{(n)})\sim(Q(U^{(1)}_{(1)}),...,Q(U^{(1)}_{(n)}))$ with $U_{(1)},...,U_{(n)}$ as the order statistics of $n$ $\textrm{Unif}(0,1)$ random variables. The $Y_{(i)}$ can be written in the same way with an independent set of $U^{(2)}_{(i)}$. Using these uniform random variables, we can rewrite $T$ as:
$$\begin{aligned}T=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_{(i)}Y_{(i)}&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nQ(U^{(1)}_{(i)})Q(U^{(2)}_{(i)})\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nQ^2(U^{(1)}_{(i)})+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nQ(U^{(1)}_{(i)})\left[Q(U^{(2)}_{(i)})-Q(U^{(1)}_{(i)})\right]
\end{aligned}$$
First term
Focusing on the first term, the order in which the elements are added does not matter, so $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nQ^2(U^{(1)}_{(i)})=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nQ^2(U^{(1)}_{i}).$$ By the strong law of large numbers, $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nQ^2(U^{(1)}_{i})\xrightarrow{a.s.}E(Q^2(U))=\int_0^1Q^2(u)du=E(X^2)=1$$
To see the second to last equality, note that $$E(X^2)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2f(x)dx=\int_0^1x^2du=\int_0^1Q^2(u)du$$ using the $u$ substitution $u=F(x)\iff x=Q(u)$.
Second term
Now, examining the second term, and converting back the quantile functions, we can apply Markov's inequality to write:
$$P\left(\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_{(i)}\left(Y_{(i)}-X_{(i)}\right)-0\right|>\epsilon\right)\leq \frac{E\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_{(i)}\left(Y_{(i)}-X_{(i)}\right)\right|}{\epsilon}$$
By the triangle inequality,
$$\begin{aligned}\frac{E\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_{(i)}\left(Y_{(i)}-X_{(i)}\right)\right|}{\epsilon}\leq \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nE\left|X_{(i)}\left(Y_{(i)}-X_{(i)}\right)\right|}{\epsilon}\\
\end{aligned}$$
Then, by Holder's inequality with $p=q=2$,
$$\begin{aligned}\frac{1}{n\epsilon}\sum_{i=1}^nE\left|X_{(i)}\left(Y_{(i)}-X_{(i)}\right)\right|&\leq \frac{1}{n\epsilon}\sum_{i=1}^n(E(X_{(i)}^2))^{1/2}\left(E\left(\left(Y_{(i)}-X_{(i)}\right)^2\right)\right)^{1/2}\\
&= \frac{1}{n\epsilon}\sum_{i=1}^n(E(X_{(i)}^2))^{1/2}\left(E\left(Y_{(i)}^2-2Y_{(i)}X_{(i)}-X_{(i)}^2\right)\right)^{1/2}\\
&= \frac{1}{n\epsilon}\sum_{i=1}^n(E(X_{(i)}^2))^{1/2}\left(E(Y_{(i)}^2)-2E(Y_{(i)})E(X_{(i)})+E(X_{(i)}^2)\right)^{1/2}\\
&= \frac{1}{n\epsilon}\sum_{i=1}^n(E(X_{(i)}^2))^{1/2}\left(2E(X_{(i)}^2)-2(E(X_{(i)}))^2\right)^{1/2}\\
&= \frac{1}{n\epsilon}\sum_{i=1}^n(E(X_{(i)}^2))^{1/2}\left(2\textrm{Var}(X_{(i)})\right)^{1/2}
\end{aligned}$$
where we used the fact that $Y_{(i)}\sim X_{(i)}$. At this point, I'm not sure how to solve in generality, but showing the result for another continuous distribution besides $N(0,1)$ might help. Let $X_i\sim Y_i\sim\textrm{Unif}(-\sqrt{3},\sqrt{3})$, which gives $E(X_i)=0,\textrm{Var}(X_i)=1$. Since $-\sqrt{3}\leq X_{(i)}\leq \sqrt{3}$, $E(X_{(i)}^2)\leq 3$. Also, we can create the transformation $X_i=\sqrt{12}(U_i-1/2)$ with $U_i\sim\textrm{Unif}(0,1)$. Then, since order is preserved in the transformation, we can apply results about the order statistics of $\textrm{Unif}(0,1)$ random variables:
$$\textrm{Var}(X_{(i)})=12\textrm{Var}(U_{(i)})=\frac{12i(n+1-i)}{(n+1)^2(n+2)}<\frac{12}{n+2}$$
Going back, we can now write the inequality:
$$\begin{aligned}\frac{1}{n\epsilon}\sum_{i=1}^n(E(X_{(i)}^2))^{1/2}\left(2\textrm{Var}(X_{(i)})\right)^{1/2}&<
\frac{1}{n\epsilon}\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{\frac{72}{n+2}}\\
&<\frac{\sqrt{72}}{\epsilon n^{1/2}}\\
&\rightarrow 0
\end{aligned}$$
Putting step 2 all together, we have $$P\left(\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_{(i)}\left(Y_{(i)}-X_{(i)}\right)-0\right|>\epsilon\right)\rightarrow 0\implies \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_{(i)}\left(Y_{(i)}-X_{(i)}\right)\xrightarrow{p} 0$$
Therefore, in the original equation:
$$T=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nQ^2(U^{(1)}_{(i)})+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nQ(U^{(1)}_{(i)})\left[Q(U^{(2)}_{(i)})-Q(U^{(1)}_{(i)})\right]$$
the first term goes to 1 and the second term goes to 0, so $T\xrightarrow{p}1$.
Clearly, to solve the original problem, we'd need some way to show $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(E(X_{(i)}^2))^{1/2}\left(\textrm{Var}(X_{(i)})\right)^{1/2}\rightarrow 0$. I searched around, but I can't find anything that shows this in generality or in the normal case.
